# How to stop text boxes from interpreting information entered as HTML

Tags: html, database, text

I'm fairly new to html and php and have an issue where I can type html into my text box and if I echo out the information from the database it will actually run the code. What I mean is...

On my website there is a textbox and in the text box they can type br or a href etc and the code will run like actuall html.

So is there a way to prevent this? CKEditor or what? All support is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

[`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) would be a good place to start. Followed by getting a clue what you're doing before you become yet another victim of terrible coding practices and security issues.